# Using Perl to sort an array using values that occur after a RegEx or symbol

Tags: arrays, sorting, perl

I have an array:

```
@all (
<side.effect signif="life.threat">myocardial infarction</side.effect>
<side.effect signif="life.threat">hypersensitivity reactions</side.effect>
<side.effect signif="life.threat">lactic acidosis</side.effect>
<side.effect signif="most.freq">vomiting</side.effect>
<side.effect signif="most.freq">diarrhea</side.effect>
);
```

I want to sort the array on the values after the opening XML tags/attributes (">) to produce this output:

```
<side.effect signif="most.freq">diarrhea</side.effect>
<side.effect signif="life.threat">hypersensitivity reactions</side.effect>
<side.effect signif="life.threat">lactic acidosis</side.effect>
<side.effect signif="life.threat">myocardial infarction</side.effect>
<side.effect signif="most.freq">vomiting</side.effect>
```

I cannot convert it to a hash as that would eliminate the tags due to replication.
I tried this but it doesn't sort them:

```
    my @sorted_all = sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map { (split)[1] } $a, $b;
    $bb <=> $aa;
} @all;
```

Comment: What do you think `split` does??? /// Also, `<=>` compares *numbers*, when you want to compare *strings*. That's what `cmp` is for. /// ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;` or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Sort::Key](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Sort::Key qw(keysort);

my @all = ( 
    q{<side.effect signif="life.threat">myocardial infarctio</side.effect>},
    q{<side.effect signif="life.threat">hypersensitivity reations</side.effect>},
    q{<side.effect signif="life.threat">lactic acidosis</sid.effect>},
    q{<side.effect signif="most.freq">vomiting</side.effect>},
    q{<side.effect signif="most.freq">diarrhea</side.effect>},
);


my @sorted = keysort { ( /">(.+?)<\// )[0] } @all;  

say for @sorted;
```

The library uses [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) when needed, to first build the comparison patterns for all items (and not re-do it at each pair comparison).  I copied input as given, typos and all.

Using a regex to parse an XML tag relies on this very specific input format. If there are going to be variations in format then please use a proper XML parser, like [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML). For example

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;

my @sorted = keysort {
    $parser -> parse_string($_)
        -> findnodes('side.effect') -> [0]
        -> textContent
} @all;
```

For this code see [XML::LibXML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod) and [XML::LibXML::Node](https://metacpan.org/release/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0128/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod).  This library comes with a lot more documentation, see the top document linked at first mention.

*For this to work I had to correct the typo `sid.effect` in one node so to have a valid XML.*

Comment: This works, but the earlier, first comment--which has been deleted for some reason--is what gave success; for the record:

      my $re=qr{^.+?">(.+?)</.+$};
say $_
    for (@sorted_all = sort { $a =~ s{$re}{$1}r cmp $b =~ s{$re}{$1}r } @all); 
      @sorted_all = sort { $a =~ s{$re}{$1}r cmp $b =~ s{$re}{$1}r } @all;

Comment: @RFA Indeed, that works as well, I don't know why they deleted their answer.  I'd recommend this library though, not only for efficiency reasons (what one doesn't see unless  _a lot_ of this is done) but for cleanliness with more complex sorting and for convenience.  Btw, if you liked that regex trick you can use it here as well:`keysort { s{">(.+?)</}{$1}r }`.  I used the match operator, and then needed to put it in list context and extract the first match, `( ... )[0]`, merely on general principle as we need a match-and-capture, not replacement.  The `s/../../r` works too